# SSL App Engine and Android Application Certificate

Tags: android, google-app-engine, ssl, encryption, https

I want to create a call in the service I am creating that has SSL so I can send some credentials over to it. I set up the SSL in the web.xml like this:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Drive</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/PosttoDrive</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

for the url and when I do this:

```
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
String algorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

URL url = new URL(DriveURL);
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

in my android application I get that it isn't a trusted certificate. I try to do a openssl to get the certificate (because I don't want to trust all) I get this error:

```
gethostbyname failure
connect:errno=2
```

What I want to do is pull the certificate, then generate an AES key, send the AES key to the app engine under SSL and then encrypt the credentials and send that to the service. Am I thinking of this right, and implementing it right?

Any help would be appreciated.